# How do I set query cache on a call issued by the seam engine

Tags: seam, seam2

```
@In
Identity identity;

Boolean newValue = identity.hasPermission(target, action);
```

Any call to the above method also does a "select role from Role r" call, which is called from the underlying seam engine. How do I set the query cache for this call as a query hint (e.g. org.hibernate.cacheable flag) so that it doesn't get called again.

Note: Role information is never bound to change, hence I view this as a unnecessary sql call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not in hibernate, but as this question is still unanswered: we extended the standard Identity class of seam for several reasons. You might want to extend it as well to help you caching the results.

As this cache is session scoped, it will have the possible benefit that it will be reloaded when the user logs on/off again - but this depends on your requirements.

Best regards,
Alexander.

```
/**
 * Extended Identity to implement i.e. caching
 */
@Name("org.jboss.seam.security.identity")
@Scope(SESSION)
@Install(precedence = Install.APPLICATION)
@BypassInterceptors
@Startup
public class MyIdentity extends Identity {

  // place a concurrent hash map here

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(Object name, String action) {
    // either use the use the cached result in the hash map ... 
    // ... or call super.hasPermission() and cache the result
  }

}
```